# Submitting after() form does not use Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

Something for the weekend. I am using the ajaxForm plugin and it works fine. But the form created using after() only submits normally to the url and does post ajax.

```
$("a.update-time").live("click", function(event) {

            event.preventDefault(); 
            var row = $(this).attr("id").split('-');

            $("#update-mini-form").remove();

            $(this).after(
                '<div id="update-mini-form"><form method="post" action="' + 'http://drupal.se/timetracker/timetracker/update_time/' + row[1] + '"> ' +
                '<input type="textfield" name="title" value="">' +
                '<input type="textfield" name="event_date" value="">' +
                '<input type="textfield" name="hours" size="2" value="">' +
                '<input type="submit" value="update">' +
                '</form></div>'                 
                );
        });

        $('#update-mini-form').live("submit", function(){

                var row = $(this).closest('a').attr("id").split('-');
                $(this).ajaxForm({
                        url: 'http://drupal.se/timetracker/timetracker/update_time/' + row[1],
                        target:$("div#row-" + row[1]),
                        type: "POST",
                });

        });
```

Comment: off topic: why don't you have only one form and move it around instead of removing and creating it again ? then you wont need to register the submit event with live. also a proper way of delegating events would be the use of on() not live.

Comment: What version of jQuery do you use? `live()` is off the stock since jQuery 1.7.

Comment: @poelinca, I thought of this first but got coders block. It's been a lomg day. I will give a try in the morning.

Comment: This is in Drupal 7 so the highest version is 1.4.4. Frustrating, but nothing I can do about now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, .live() works by binding to a delegate handler to the document element and listening for events to bubble up, right? As Vishal and Poelinca Dorin noted, you should be using .on() for the current versions of jQuery.

I think your problem may be because your mini-form submission handler doesn't prevent the default submission from happening. Try this:

```
$("a.update-time").live("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var row = $(this).attr("id").split('-');

    $("#update-mini-form").remove();

    $(this).after(
        '<div id="update-mini-form"><form method="post" action="' + 'http://drupal.se/timetracker/timetracker/update_time/' + row[1] + '"> ' +
        '<input type="textfield" name="title" value="">' +
        '<input type="textfield" name="event_date" value="">' +
        '<input type="textfield" name="hours" size="2" value="">' +
        '<input type="submit" value="update">' +
        '</form></div>'                 
        );
});

// Note: You should probably replace $(document) with a more specific container element
$(document).on("submit", "#update-mini-form", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var row = $(this).closest('a').attr("id").split('-');
    $(this).ajaxForm({
        url: 'http://drupal.se/timetracker/timetracker/update_time/' + row[1],
        target:$("div#row-" + row[1]),
        type: "POST",
    });

});
```

Comment: Of course, doing $(document) is not efficient -- you should replace that with the container element to improve performance.  Since I didn't know much about your HTML I just left it like that for now so you could see if it fixes your "AJAX not working" problem and then improve it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got this working. I the advise about a single form but live() was still necessary. I guess because when you move/copy something with JS it is still is not part of the page. I also had the selector wrong but fixing did not help. Also closest was being killed by moving the form and live() does not help this. So I had to change the system to put id in the form. This is what I used:

php:

```
$output .=  '<div><form method="post" style="display:none" id="update-mini-form" action="' . 'http://drupal.se/timetracker/timetracker/update_time">' .
                '<input type="textfield" name="title" value="">' .
                '<input type="textfield" name="event_date" value="">' .
                '<input type="hidden" name="id_mini_form" id="id-mini-form" value="">' .
                '<input type="textfield" name="hours" size="2" value="">' .
                '<input type="button" id="sendUpdate" value="update">' .
                '</form></div>';                
    //$output .= '<pre>' .print_r($all, 1) . '</pre>'; 
    print $output;
```

js:

```
$("a.update-time").live("click", function(event) {

            event.preventDefault(); 
            var row = $(this).attr("id").split('-');

            $("#id-mini-form").val(row[1]);

            $(this).after($("#update-mini-form").show());


        });

        $("#sendUpdate").live("click",function() {          
            $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://drupal.se/timetracker/timetracker/update_time/",
                        data: $('#update-mini-form').serialize(),
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(result){

                            $("#update-mini-form").hide();
                            alert(result);
                        }
            });

            return false;           

        });
```